# The difference between Detached Homes and Townhouses

Tags: meaning, difference

A tutorial video calls the following image (A) as Townhouses

[image]

and calls the following image (B) as Detached Homes

[image]

what is the difference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-family_detached_home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detached houses are detached from one another - there is a clear space of air between them.  They do not share walls.  Townhouses, in that Am.Eng. sense of the word, are terraced.  They do share walls.  (Note that Br.Eng may use townhouse differently.)

Comment: No, I don't think it does.

Comment: @KateBunting: Dunno about the US context, but in the UK I don't think "townhouse" has any strong associations for or against having party walls (terrace, semi, or detached). The main identifying characteristic is that a townhouse has ***at least three floors*** (land being in short supply in densely-packed urban areas, wealthy people seeking to upgrade must build ***upwards*** rather than ***outwards***).

Comment: I didn't mean "may use it differently" as in "it might do, I don't know".  I meant "it may use it differently depending on the circumstance".  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Townhouse_(Great_Britain)).  This is the sense I feel like I grew up with - town vs country home, with no definite association of terracing - although as the article notes, property developers and estate agents have increasingly pushed an Am.Eng type use of the word.